# Is AJAX taking up my CPU power?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My server CPU power when visiting the page is using 11% / 100% every tab that is open is another 11%. Here is the code for my JScript:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('pop');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "Population: " + ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "count.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

And here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
$con = @mysql_connect("31.xx.x.xxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  echo('?');
  }
@mysql_select_db("archstud_db", $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chars");
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$num = $num;
echo $num;

@mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I am also using setInterval() with my JScript with window.onload starting the setinterval function refreshing the JScript every 6 seconds.

What is taking up so much CPU ?
Also, how do i fix it?

Comment: Check the `COUNT(*)` mysql function. PS: `$num = $num;` o_O

Comment: MySQL statement bitching aside, I'm guessing the issue you're having has to do with the setInterval() possibly?  Maybe calling the function over and over and over again?

Comment: I requested it in a comment on an answer. Can we see the setInterval, please?

Answer (score 1):

The OP has not pasted the important part of the code, and requests to see it are unsuccessful, so I will hazard a guess and back it up with reasonable explanations. His **server**'s CPU is being overloaded - this means that whatever happens, there's something pinging the server a gianormous amount of times. We also know that every tab adds 11% locally, which means that something is doing a gianormous amount of things in the browser.

The OP stated about setInterval. I am ready to bet that he has the following line, somewhere:

```
setInterval(ajaxFunction, 6);
```

Which, he may believe, pings every 6 seconds. In fact, it pings every six **milliseconds**, which would both explain the server-side and client-side load without freezing the page.

A quick workaround is the following:

```
setInterval(ajaxFunction, 6000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you still using a deprecated library (mysql)?

Have you heard of indexes - "SELECT * FROM chars" may be screwing things up.

Any why are you doing a refresh every 6 seconds?

Comment: If someone wants to select everything from a table - then indexes won't help (by definition). Not an answer.

Comment: are you sure you completely understand how indexes work? If so - could you please explain how indexes would help with `SELECT * FROM tbl` query (assuming a person needs to retrieve everything from a table)?

Comment: @zerkms - Yes I do know - It would narrow down the search parameters. Does the user require the whole table? I think not as that kinda makes the whole concept of a database redundant.

Comment: "Does the user require the whole table" --- if you need the whole table - then you need the whole table. "I think not as that kinda makes the whole concept of a database redundant." --- it doesn't. Otherwise provide a link to the such "concepts" which are violated.

Comment: PS: anyway, OP needs `COUNT(*)` and its behaviour is irrelevant to indexes

Comment: How do i use count() with a mysql query? I'm trying to find the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: have you checked my comment to the question?

Comment: Yes. I have removed $num = $num; How do i use count() with a mysql query? I'm trying to find the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @zerkms - BTW an index keeps track of statistics and therefore enables the engine to know the dynamics of the various tables.

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: I have given you an advice - have you made a research after it? Have you tried to put "mysql count" to google?

Comment: @Ed Heal: how is it related to `COUNT(*)` particularly?

Comment: "Check the COUNT(*) mysql function." - zerkms. :\
I just want to know how to fix this. Php doesn't seem to be the problem though. Such a small peice of code.

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: right. Have you checked it? Are you here to learn how to do your work or for getting us doing your work for free?

Comment: Define "checked it" because i have no idea what you mean. I've looked at the PHP Manual for the COUNT(*) function yes, and the PHP code works fine when not being run in a JavaScript AJAX function. That's why i am assuming the issue is either AJAX or JS.

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: so what is your new query with `COUNT(*)`? "the PHP code works fine" --- it doesn't. As a first step you need to rewrite your query to use `COUNT(*)` since the current solution is terrible.

Comment: Idk how to, i checked the Count(*) manual it does not show how i would use it with mysql queries. I tried count($result) but the issue is that it always returns the value "1"

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: show the mysql manual page about `COUNT()` that doesn't show how to use it.

Comment: @zerkms - Database engines store things like the size of the various tables. Snap of the figures the engine has the number of rows at its figure tips. Does not need to count them!

Comment: @Ed Heal: 1. It's only true for `myisam`, not `innodb` 2. Still, how is it related to **indexes**?

Comment: Nevermind. I googled how to use COUNT(*) with mysql databases and found it out via another stackoverflow page. And that would be the official php manual website, first thing on google. Doesn't show an example for mysql. HOWEVER! This did not stop the 11% CPU issue, therefore proving my point that COUNT(*) has no relevance to the issue. Thanks for helping though, any other suggestions guys (JScript, Ajax?)

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: what process does consume 11%?

Comment: @zerkms Idk, how do i find that out exactly? My premium server is being hosted by Cpanel.

Comment: @Douglas Mckee: what OS is it?

Comment: @zerkms Linux. Btw, thanks for sticking with me and helping me with the issue even though we haven't found a solution yet. :)

Comment: Anyone still got some suggestions? It has to either be the setInterval() or the AJAX/JScript. I'm still googling if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: Whoever said indices are the cause of the issue is talking through their asses. Even without a single index, MySQL keeps an internal count of rows on a table. As for what may be causing your issue...can we see the entire JS, please? I'd like to know how you call your setInterval. I have a feeling you're doing `setInterval(ajaxUpdate, 6);` and not `setInterval(ajaxUpdate,6000);` which will cause your script to run every 6 **milliseconds**...